# Razor Helper in App_Code and Javascript

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create a component that can be consumed by multiple views and I want to associate Javascript to manipulate elements in my component.
So I created a HtmlHelper in App_Code RAZOR like this:

```
@helper HswToolbar()
{

    <header>
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-flat pull-left hswbutton">Quitter</button>

        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-flat pull-right hswbutton">Détail</button>
    </header>


}
```

In Index.cshtml, I have a file that should allow me to manage interactions with the user of trigger actions. But it is never realized.
For example, with this code in the _Layout:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/hsw/HtmlHelper.js")
```

and my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".hswbutton").click(function (e) {
        alert("htmlhelper click OK");
    });
});
```

Can you help me ?
Or are there other solutions?

Comment: What is in the external JS file? Just include it in the script bundles.

Comment: "It does not work" is not very specific. That certainly *should* work, but comments are not the place for code... please edit your answer to incldue all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the buttons, then could you try this in order to debug the code in the JS?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("code loaded");
    $(".hswbutton").on("click",function (e) {
        alert("htmlhelper click OK");
    });
});
```

Maybe you load asynchrinously the html, or maybe js is not loaded... so first alert test if the js is loaded and second if button is clicked. Your onclick only works if dom elements are loaded with the page (not ajax for instance)